# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with Heroku, Node, Express, SSL

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku, https

I recently enabled SSL for my Heroku-hosted website, wildcodemonkey.com, but when I visit it in Chrome I see the error "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

My research indicated that the SSL connection terminates at Heroku's router, which then passes the request along via HTTP to my express/node site. Consequently, I did not set up 'https' in my server and have been expecting standard HTTP connections.

My SSL configuration is such that my CSR, key and cert were passed along to Heroku. I'm using the SSL option baked into Heroku, not a third-party resource/addon. After enabling SSL in my app's settings I changed my DNS to reflect the new endpoint (wildcodemonkey.com.herokudns.com instead of wildcodemonkey.com.herokuapp.com), this is the endpoint I was told to use when I configured SSL on Heroku, directly copied and pasted from the settings page after setting up ssl.

I do see morgan logging GET requests when I hit the domain, so it does look like everything is making it end to end, so I'm not sure where the issue is occurring.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wildcodemonkey.com&s=107.21.206.81&latest) report the certificate chain of this site is incomplete. While desktop browsers often but not always will work around this problem mobile browsers and other applications will usually not. Check the documentation provided by your CA which chain certificates need to be configured.

Comment: Bingo! Added all intermediate certificates and now things are working. Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: For anyone else who happens upon this, I used https://certificatechain.io/ ti generate the complete certificate chain for use with Heroku.