# SSL Protocol Error when Accessing Heroku site using GoDaddy-issued SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

I'm trying to enable a standard SSL certificate for my Heroku-hosted website, categorizedtweets.com, a Rails app.

**This is the DNS record on Go Daddy:**
[image]

**This is what my forwarding looks like:**

[image]

**This is what my Heroku domain section looks like:**
[image]

I also un-commented the `config.force_ssl = true` in my `production.rb` file to force all users to access the site over SSL

And yet, accessing https://www.categorizedtweets.com/, yields an error that reads: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`:
[image]

After reading through similar roadblocks experienced by other devs, I suspect it has something to do with how my *[certificate chain is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332825/6321066)*, and how chain certificates need to be configured -- but how do I do that?

A bit of background - I purchased the standard SSL certificate from a third-party source (GoDaddy). I followed [this site](https://medium.com/@arsamesqajar/heroku-godaddy-and-ssl-certs-walk-into-a-bar-11cf72016e73) which outlines how to generate an approved SSL. I uploaded the certs to Heroku.

Comment: Important to add:

http://www.categorizedtweets.com works fine but https://www.categorizedtweets.com will yield an error.

I currently have the `config.force_ssl = true` grayed out in my `production.rb` file, because if not, it would force all users to access the site using SSL, which would yield the error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my application pages were partially encrypted -- and so while my app wasn't outright failing the certification tests, it wasn't exactly passing it either.

My app had several *mixed content* pages -- which is an HTTPS page that has content that was fetched using HTTP. Simply put, I was making HTTP API calls, instead of HTTPS API calls.

Once I made the switch from `http` to `https` in all my appropriate places (my database, and a script) -- I was in the clear.

To check out a listing of your application's *Non-Secure origins* -- that is, content that is causing your page to be a mixed-content page:

Chrome Users:
Check out the *Security* tab in your Dev tools. The non-secure origins listing will be in the left column

FireFox Users:
Inspect the page; it'll appear in the Console tab.